# jQuery AJAX success assignment to object

Tags: jquery, ajax

Making a successful jQuery AJAX call but don't understand why the returned data doesn't get assigned to theProductData object in the following function:-

```
function getProductDetails(getSku) {
//Get Full Product Details
var theProductData = new Object();
theProductData.description = '';
theProductData.price = '';
theProductData.stockLevel = '';
$.ajax({
    url: baseUrl + '/product/' + getSku,
    success: function (response) {
        theProductData.description = response.Description,
        theProductData.price = response.FormattedSellPrice,
        theProductData.stockLevel = response.FormattedStockLevel;
    }
});

console.log(theProductData);
return theProductData;
}
```

The console output is:

```
Object {description: "", price: "", stockLevel: ""}
```

The data is definitely being returned as I can see it in the devtools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Ajax call is asynchronous by definition (check the acronym).
As a consequence, the program flow proceeds after the call.
At that time, the response is not there yet.

When the response is finally available, a callback is called: your success code. Only there you can print it and proceed with the stuff that depends on it.

Here's the order happening there:

1. Declaration of your objects
2. Ajax call requested
3. Your printing wrongly before time
   ...
4. Later, server response has arrived and your success callback is executed

Comment: Using jsfiddle.net : https://jsfiddle.net/craig100/dqfvuc3L/ This is what I have now and the FormattedSellPrice is still 0.  A step closer?

Comment: You were a step coser... But the issue is: do not depend on the return value of your newly created function (it is wrong in Ajax and anyway, you weren't returning anything). Instead, depend on the success callback. Do your assignment stuff only there.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dqfvuc3L/1/ check now. The code is not runnable so I could no test it.

Comment: Thanks, the issue is still the same really, that you can't update an external variable outside a loop. The value of price set in the function is only available in the function. Hence it still shows the value it had when initiated before the function. I'll rearchitect the whole thing as this isn't going to work. Thanks

Comment: If you can't update outside, update it inside. That is how is supposed to go in async stuff.

Comment: And pass it along to your function, so it can update it itself on success.